# Screen flashes when typing if touchpad accidentally touched

Tags: keyboard, 16.04, touchpad

I just upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04. When typing if I happen to also be touching the touchpad the screen flashes, temporarily going black. It doesn't happen when I type this (in firefox), but it happens in the Gnome terminal and the gedit text editor, and even with the calculator. I never encountered this problem with 15.10. Perhaps I was just lucky and never touched the touchpad while typing, but that's unlikely.

Is there some fix for this or should I report it as a bug? If I should report it, how do I do that?

EDIT: It also seems to do it occasionally without touching the touchpad but just when typing.

EDIT2: About the graphics card, from `lspci -v`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Latitude E6410
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 70b0 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Did you try to set "Disable while typing" in System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad?

Comment: I don't have that option there. And it would still be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly this issue.

That is to say when keying text into terminal/vim/whatever any inadvertent touch of the touchpad doesn't just move the cursor but also causes the screen to flash.

Yes, it is possible to disable the touchpad when typing and there are good reasons to do this if palm detection isn't enough to stop the cursor flying about as you type. But I agree with the original post: doing this doesn't fix the underlying issue, it just makes it less likely to happen because it becomes impossible to register a keystroke and a cursor movement at the same time.

It's also worth pointing out that I am not talking about 'flickering' here (as reported elsewhere) but an effect akin to a  visual bell i.e the whole screen flashes. Perhaps this is in fact what is happening: making a keystroke and a cursor movement via the touchpad at the same time is an illegal operation?

Re-installing 14.04 completely resolves the issue for me.

I am/was running 16.04 on a  Dell Latitude with i5.